# Exercise for the identity theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Question : If $f$ and $g$ are analytic functions on domain $\mathbb{D}$ and so is the product $\overline{f}g$ on $\mathbb{D}$.
Then, $f$ is a constant or $g\equiv 0$ identically

I do not know how to start. If not an answer, I hope  the hint for Question.

1. $\overline{f}$ means a conjugate function for $f$
2. This exercise is included in the section for The identity Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $g\not \equiv 0,$ then there is an open disc $U\subset D$ where $g$ is nonzero. On $U$ we can divide by $g$ to see that $\overline f$ is analytic on $U.$

Comment: Additionally, In such conditions, If $g$ is zero on open disk $U \in D$ then Can i always say that $g$ is identically $0$ on $D$ ? I mean, Is it always possible to expand on the $D$?

Comment: Sure, the identity principle tells you this.